# Is Flutter Supports Detecting Beacons and getting the data from beacon

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to know whether flutter application can detect the beacon and get the data from beacon.
Will flutter application detects beacons when the app is closed? If so what is the approach ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/beacons_plugin

Comment: Can I get any application code related to beacons?